# How don't validate file content on build

Tags: webpack

i'm trying to include a lib in my project, but i keep getting a error. I cannot alter the file that i'm trying to import.

This is the error that i'm getting.

> Error: Cannot find module './img/alerta.png' from
>   'C:\Users\rumbelino\Documents\Mobile_AppCartoes\bcmp_mobile\app-es6\src\lib'

The line that is generating this error is this one:

```
var msg = '<div class="imagem"><img src="img/alerta.png"/></div><div class="mensagem"><ul> ';
```

This is how i'm importing the file

```
import './AWBE-1.2.0.lib'
```

And this is the config in my webpack.config.js

```
{
  test: /\.lib\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].js',
            },
          },
          'extract-loader',
          'html-loader',
        ],
},
```

What i'm trying to do is to just export this files in my final build, i don't have to validate the code inside, there's a way to just ignore all imports inside the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "export this files in my final build"? Would you like to copy this lib in the output direcotry? If so, use the CopyWebpackPlugin for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem replacing the html-loader with the text-loader.

```
{
        test: /\.lib\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].js',
            },
          },
          'extract-loader',
          'text-loader',
        ],
},
```